# TypeError: '_AtIndexer' object is not callable in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` object named `df`, and I want to generate a list of properly formatted dates. (`datetime` module is properly imported)

I wrote:

```
dates = [datetime.date(df.at(index, "year"), df.at(index, "month"), df.at(index, "day")) for index in df.index]
```

which gives the error in the title.

If it helps, this is the value of `df.head()`:

```
   year  month  day  smoothed   trend
0  2011      1    1    391.26  389.76
1  2011      1    2    391.29  389.77
2  2011      1    3    391.33  389.78
3  2011      1    4    391.36  389.78
4  2011      1    5    391.39  389.79
```

(This is new to me, so I have likely misinterpreted the docs)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`df.at` is not a *callable* but a *property* that supports indexing. So change parantheses to square brackets around it:

```py
df.at[index, "year"]
```

i.e., `(` to `[` and similar for closing.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using `[` instead of `(` you can achieve your goal simply by

```
pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])
```